# Text Appearing Between the Lines in Scrivener

Tags: creative-writing, editing, scrivener

I have been editing scrivener across devices, and when I edit text across multiple devices, the text appears midway between the lines. I can find no way to prevent this from happening in the first place, nor any way to fix it in documents I have already edited.

Here is a picture:

[image]

Any help appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I strongly recommend that you get in touch with the Scrivener community. They may be able to give you a much faster answer. You might also try to check if that is a known (or unknown) bug. Good luck.

Comment: Question: if one of your devices is Scrivener Desktop, have you customized the fonts and line spacing in the Desktop version? Also, is it Scrivener 2 or 3 on the desktop?

Answer (score -1):

I presume that the different applications don't use exactly the same formatting rules and thus it cannot work properly.

*I have the same kind of problem if I highlight things in a same book in my Kindle app and also in my Kindle device. One added functionnalities on the app overlap the highlighting function in the normal Kindle device and create bugs.*

Depending on the devices you can find help here :
[Mac](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=2) - [Windows](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewforum.php?f=30) - [General support](https://www.literatureandlatte.com/learn-and-support)

I advise you to be very specific in your questions there (which devices are used, application version, give files as examples).

If you don't find then maybe you must limit yourself to only one main device (or at least have the exact same configuration between a workstation and a laptop by example). The last option would be to work on an [alternative of Scrievner](https://alternativeto.net/software/scrivener/)

Answer (score -1):

This will not answer your question directly but provide you with a possible alternative which could be a workaround for any text formatting issues with your current setup.

If you are not too far down the path of writing then you might want to look at LaTeX environment and TexStudio editor which would allow you to create professional quality books from scratch and only start worrying about the presentation once you are far enough in the process. You start off with just structuring your document, then you can add tables, charts, graphs, illustrations, title pages, TOC, LOF, LOT, etc.

It is multi-platform as well and you can work on the same document on almost any device in the world as long as the TeX distribution is not too old. I often work under Windows XP, but also under Windows 10, FreeBSD, and modern Linux.

PS: I do not know if Scrivener is well represented on SE. The advantage of LaTeX is that there is a site for it [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/) and it is one of the best resources that Internet ever had.

Comment: Much as I love LaTeX, it is a typesetting suite, and does not provide anywhere near same utility or work flow benefits that a writer's composition software suite does. Scrivener has an output path to LaTeX which I use for actual typesetting, so it's not like Scrivener has to be abandoned to use LaTeX, and I can personally attest to the gulf of difference between writing in a tex/LaTeX editor (which I've done lots of; I like TeXShop and sometimes vim) and writing in something like Scrivener or Ulysses, even when targetting LaTeX output.